# Error: Embed URL is invalid for this scenario. Please use Power BI REST APIs to get the valid URL

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have implemented powerbi-javascript embedded custmization with Angular 9 web app. I can be able see dashboard charts view, but whenever I change embedUrl ( which is working in browser ) it shows blank page and getting error -

```
    Error: Embed URL is invalid for this scenario. Please use Power BI REST APIs to get the valid
```

Configuration Object -

```
const config: any = {
  type: 'report',
  uniqueId: '40cc1ea5-4ef2-4e63-8c4d-2970a6584be6',
  permissions: this.model.Permissions.All,
  embedUrl: 'embed-url',
  accessToken: 'access-token',
  settings: { panes: { filters: { visible: true }, pageNavigation: { visible: false } } 
  };
```

Thanks,

Comment: And what happens when you follow the advise given by the error message and use the embedUrl returned by the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/getdashboardingroup#example)? Obviously you are using wrong URL, because you can;t navigate to the embedUrls in the browser.

Comment: When I use embedded url from REST API it's only loading the page not able to view it. now  i am trying to debug it again.